# Get gridcontrol records as an array

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

How can I get `gridcontrol` records as an array?

I set an array as a `datasource` for a `gridcontrol (devExpress component)`.

```
PersonFamily4grid[] tmpPersonFamily = new PersonFamily4grid[PersonFamiliesCOUNT];
for (int i = 0; i < PersonFamiliesCOUNT; i++)
{
    tmpPersonFamily[i] = new PersonFamily4grid();
    tmpPersonFamily[i].BirthDate = PersonFamilies[i].BirthDate;
    tmpPersonFamily[i].Job = PersonFamilies[i].Job;
    tmpPersonFamily[i].CodeMelli = PersonFamilies[i].CodeMelli;
    tmpPersonFamily[i].NameFamily = PersonFamilies[i].NameFamily;
    tmpPersonFamily[i].Nesbat = FamilyInfo_cbe_Nesbat.Properties.Items[PersonFamilies[i].Nesbat].ToString();
    tmpPersonFamily[i].Taahol = FamilyInfo_cbe_Taahol.Properties.Items[Convert.ToInt32(PersonFamilies[i].Taahol)].ToString();
}
grid_Family.DataSource = tmpPersonFamily;
```

Now when the user changes data in `gridcontrol`, I want to get changes from the grid and affect my base array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When user changes data in gridcontrol i want get changes from grid and
>   affect my base array.

Why are you creating temporary array if you want to reflect changes to main array `PersonFamilies`. just simply assign `PersonFamilies` to gridControl's data source  and it will automatically reflect changes to `PersonFamilies`.

If you know that class object are reference type, so their reference will not change if you assign the array directly to the gridControls data source as:

```
grid_Family.DataSource = PersonFamilies;
```

After making some changes to your data in grid view, check the object of `PersonFamilies` array that they are updated or not. It will surely update the array of objects.

If you want to work on some customized Data that contained in your `PersonFamilies` array then you can get the Iterate your temporary array `tmpPersonFamily` without getting it through the `DataSource` property of GridControl and it all depends on you how you will manipulate or reflect changes to your main array `PersonFamilies`.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PersonFamiliesCOUNT; i++)
{                
    PersonFamilies[i].BirthDate = tmpPersonFamily[i].BirthDate;
    PersonFamilies[i].Job = tmpPersonFamily[i].Job;
    PersonFamilies[i].CodeMelli = tmpPersonFamily[i].CodeMelli;
    PersonFamilies[i].NameFamily = tmpPersonFamily[i].NameFamily;  
}
```

Hope this help..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
PersonFamily4grid[] personFamily = (PersonFamily4grid[])grid_Family.DataSource;
```